# What are the different types of datatypes?

Tags: python-3.x, int, int64, int32

I'm working on a Machine learning model, the data I am having is very large, I am thinking of reducing the size of each column, actual size is `int64`. I want to know what are the types of `Int` from `int4` to `int64` and are there any data types for an object like `object8`. I want to know all datatypes bit sizes.

Comment: The object type are just pointers to python objects, they are always the same size

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you work with pandas and thus numpy.
The numpy types are described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html), the smallest integer are `int8` or `uint8`. Pandas adds some types to those existing in numpy. There are describe [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dtypes).